# Mysql AND search on multiple row with multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sql-like

Let's say I have this table :

```
id    |  field1  |  field2  |  field3  |  field4
 0    |  pear    |  peach   |  fruit   |  california
 1    |  apple   |  peas    |  xxxxxx  |  cupertino
 2    |  apple   |  peach   |  xxxxxx  |  san francisco
```

If the user search for "apple peach" I want to get the line

```
2    |  apple   |  peach   |  xxxxxx  |  san francisco
```

same result expected for the search "applepie san francisco" or "applepeach fran"

So what would be the mysql request to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONCAT(field1, ' ', field2) = 'apple peach';
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONCAT(field1, ' ', field2) like '%apple%' and CONCAT(field1, ' ', field2) like '%peach%'; is what I want

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   your_table
WHERE 
   'apple' IN (field1, field2, field3) 
   AND 'peach' IN (field1, field2, field3)
```

Comment: this seems what I want to do but I don't want to search on the exact word apple, it can be applepie for instance, will that do it?

Comment: @Mathieu So if `applepeach` is the word, all the rows in your example will be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Simply enough, you want to check if `field1` is "apple" and `field2` is "peach", so `WHERE field1='apple' AND field2='peach'` will do it.

I get the feeling that what you want is a little more complex though. One solution might be to  replace the spaces in the search terms with commas, then use the `IN` SQL operator to search within that.

Something like the following may therefore work:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE 
field1 IN ('apple','peach') OR 
field2 IN ('apple','peach') OR 
field3 IN ('apple','peach') OR  
field4 IN ('apple','peach')
```

Comment: Alternatively, swap the order of `fieldX` and `apple,peach`, similar to xdazz's answer.

Comment: this will select all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You will be using some kind of parameters to fit your search. So:

```
SELECT `id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`
  FROM Table1
 WHERE whatyouarelookingfor_1 IN (field1, field2, field3) 
   AND whatyouarelookingfor_2 IN (field1, field2, field3)
```

Edited to add the IN clause as previously it was only selecting from one field

That is an easy query, check this working **[SQL Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8886e/2)**.

Comment: Given the question states that the user searches for "apple peach", I think the OP wants a more generalised approach.

Comment: `field1 IN (field1, field2, field3) 
   AND field2 IN (field1, field2, field3)` will always be true.

Comment: The OP will be using parameters for sure...will edit again to make it more readable